# GOTO returning incorrect syntax

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a piece of code that runs a bunch of echos to display text waits for a second, then changes the command prompt's text and background color to a random color, in a half a second interval and goes back to the start, but it checks if it ran the echos already so it skips straight to the color changing, so that it does it twice, but it is saying that the command syntax for the goto :z (line 18) is invalid, and I cannot see why it isn't working. The code is as follows

```
set a=0
set HEX=0123456789ABCDEF
:a
rem (Echoes here)
if %a%==0 goto :c 
if %a%==1 goto :b
:c
@TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK >null
goto :b
:b
if %a%==0 goto :x
if %a%==1 goto :y
:x
set /a "a=1"
goto :z
:y
set /a "a=0"
goto :z
:z
if %a%==1
goto :f
if %a%==0
goto :g
:f
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul
set /a rand1=%random% %% 16
set /a rand2=%random% %% 16
call set hexcolors=%%HEX:~%rand1%,1%%%%HEX:~%rand2%,1%%
color %hexcolors%
:g
goto :a
```

line 28 was originally `if %a%a(...)`, but it was corrected to `if %a%(...)`.

Comment: Don't use quotes with set /a.

Comment: Two of your `IF` commands are incorrect. You don't have it doing anything after the `IF`.  `if %a%==1` and `if %a%a==0`.  Do you mean to have the `GOTO :f` and `goto :g` with the previous lines?

Comment: @RGuggisberg, you can most certainly use quotes with `SET /A`.  It literally says you can in the help file

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for pointing that out, I've been messing with those lines and I must've forgotten to place the goto's back in their place

Comment: Ok, using the corrections made in the comments, and the changes in the [EDIT], I managed to get the batch running back again, but the timing seems to be off. I wanted to have it display the text for a whole second while changing the colors every half a second (hence the colors changing twice)... Can someone help me with that?

Comment: That will not work, the timeout command runs seperate from the color command, so you are runing timeout, waiting one second, then running color, you cannot run a command locally while running another command... This example is as close as you will get it. `timeout 1 | color 1 & timeout 1 | color 2`

Comment: TBF, even the `color` randomisation is poor, because there's no code to prevent both background and foreground from matching, and the `color` command does not work when each hex number matches. I suppose in order to have a proper effect, it should also check to make sure that the random pair does not match the previous random pair too! I would also look to see if I could optimise the code to run quicker too, that would certainly help with potential timing issues.